# Django form PUT and DELETE http method

Tags: django, rest, tastypie

I'm using Django Tastypie in order to have a Rest API. It works well.

Now, I would like to use my Rest API in a django form. I know web browsers can't send a `PUT` or a `DELETE` http method (only `GET` and `POST`).

For example, to solve the problem with `ExpressJS` (A `NodeJS` web framework) :

```
<input type="hidden" name="_method" value="delete"/>
```

I can use this hack.

Is it a way to do the same thing using Django Form ?

Answer (score 2):

TastyPie supports this internally using the X-Http-Method-Override header, but that it doesn't sound like headers are any more accessible that method overrides.  On the off chance that you can do this, see [here](https://github.com/toastdriven/django-tastypie/blob/master/tastypie/resources.py#L459).

Your best bet is probably to use a Django middleware like this:

```
METHODS = [ 'GET', 'PUT', 'POST', 'DELETE' ]

class DjangoMethodMiddleware(object):
    def process_request(self, request):
        meth = request.REQUEST.get('_method', None)
        if meth is None:
            return
        if meth in METHODS:
            request.method = meth
        else:
            pass # TODO: logging?
```

Stash this in a middleware.py in your site, then you'll then need to load this middleware in your Django settings.  Magic!

Answer (score 1):

I think you can send Put or delete using javascript like this

```
$("your_form_id").submit(function(e){
    $.ajax({
        url: 'your url',
        type: "PUT",
        data: $("your_form_id").serialize(),
        cache: false,
        dataType: "text",
        success: function(data){
            do_something()
        },
        error: function() {
            console.log("ERROR");
        }
    });
});
```

Or even this hack method of your's will work.... you will have to check for this value on server side and then call he rest API accordingly.

Comment: Why do you use strings for boolean options?!